# How do I store and iterate over a result set in a MySQL Stored Proc?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm relatively new to MySQL stored procs, so I was hoping someone could help me out here. I want to call my stored proc (maybe pass in one `IN` param) and have it do the following:

1. `SELECT` some data
2. Iterate over the records
3. Perform some operations on a few of the fields in each record including some `INSERT`s in other tables based on the data it finds.

My problem is that I don't know how to store the `SELECT` data set and iterate the records. I know how to `declare` and `set` stuff like `int` and `text`, but not full data sets. How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: "Teach me the procedural SQL programming language" seems overly broad for a StackOverflow question. Have you considered reading a tutorial or a book? Or the MySQL manual at least? http://www.amazon.com/MySQL-Stored-Procedure-Programming-Harrison/dp/0596100892/ref=tmm_pap_title_0?ie=UTF8&qid=1296599594&sr=8-2 I'm voting to close this as not a real question.

Comment: This was hardly that kind of question. I didn't know what all it entailed. The "MySQL Cursors" answer is very helpful, since I didn't even know that existed. Thanks anyways.

Comment: It's true, iterating over a loop using nothing but SQL syntax is a fairly uncommon operation.

Comment: It would be nice if one could iterate like this:

FOR (id, data) AS SELECT id, data FROM test.t1 BEGIN
   ## ... do something...
END

Comment: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68758&thanks=4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look into MySql Cursors

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html

Comment: this is great and i think it's what i'm looking for. i had no idea these even existed!